# Nodehandle destroyed and shutdown the ros node

Tags: ros, nodehandle, shutdown, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I was wondering what would happen to the previously created subscriptions and publications and services after the nodehandle is destroyed? I have experieced such case: create a nodehandle in the constructor of the class and in my main() I just create a object of the class. The constructor will be called when the object is created and the nodehandle will experience starting the node, subscribe and publish, and shutting down the node as the life of circle of the nodehande is within the constructor and after that the nodehandle (lets assume it is the only one nodehandle in this example) will be destroyed and the shutdown() will be invoked.

Will this work? Will the publish and subcribe work in this way below? Thank you all.

Class A {

A

{
ros::NodeHandle private_nh("~");
pub = private_nh.advertise...
sub_ = private_nh.subscribe...

}

}

int main()

{

ros::init(...);

A a;

ros::spin();

}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142066/nodehandle-destroyed-and-shutdown-the-ros-node/) by [dalishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4790/dalishi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2014-03-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dalishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4790/dalishi/) on 2014-03-19**:
The nodehandle declared in the constructor should end its life cycle (destroyed) after the constructor function has been successfully executed, which according to the http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown, the destroy of last nodehandle instance will kill all open subscriptions, publications, service calls, and service servers. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can always make sure there exists another NodeHandle outside of your class, e.g. in the main function, which is initialized before you create the object and lives as long as you want the node to live. However, as @Wolf points out, I see no benefit in not rather storing a node handle as a (private) member of your class and avoid potential bugs of your class depending on the existance of an external node handle.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dalishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4790/dalishi/) on 2014-03-20**:
Hi demmeln, thanks for your reply. The reason I raised this problem is I have seen NavfnRos as in navfn_ros.cpp of the navigation stack, it declared temporary NodeHandle in the constructor and no other member NodeHandle nor external NodeHandle in the main(), which confused me. I will take your advice.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes this will work. You can create nodehandles anywhere in your process after ros::init. After ros::spin() has finished, your class instance goes out of scope, thereby its destructor (possibly implicitly created by compiler) is called. It will also destruct your member NodeHandle and thereby shutdown subscribers.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-03-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dalishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4790/dalishi/) on 2014-03-19**:
Hi Thanks for your reply. If the nodehandle is a member variable of my class, that would definitely work as you described. However, I want to know the case what if the nodehandle is not a member variable but a temporary variable in a member function like in the constructor as in my example. Thanks.

**Comment by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on 2014-03-20**:
I am afraid that won't work. See http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/roscpp/html/classros_1_1NodeHandle.html Destructor and  advertise doc. Why do you not want to have the NodeHandle as private class member?

**Comment by [dalishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4790/dalishi/) on 2014-03-20**:
Hi Thanks. I actually write my class in exactly the same as you suggested that is making the NodeHandle as private class member. The reason I raised this post is I have seen many codes in the ros community that did not do like this. For example, that NavfnRos as in navfn_ros.cpp of the navigation stack.

**Comment by [dalishi](https://answers.ros.org/users/4790/dalishi/) on 2014-03-20**:
that NavfnRos as in navfn_ros.cpp of the navigation stack declared the NodeHandles in the constructor of the class and in the main() there is no other NodeHandle maintained. The same case is in the sbpl_lattice_planner. So this is actually confusing me of the way that how to use the NodeHandles.